# SSRS Pass parameter / Field value from 1 table to another

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS 2012.

I have two datasets. I have two tables.
The first table contains a contract Id which is used as parameter in the second dataset.
I want to set the parameter as the contractId (ie Fields!ContractId.Value, or ReportItems!Contract1.Value) or something like that but nothing works because of different limitations.

If I would be using a subreport that would have been easy just pass the Field!Contract.Value from the 1st dataset as the parameter for the second and there you go. But since we want to call the report using SQL server agent, I cannot use subreport since the agent is limited and does not accept subreport.

So I believe my only option is to use two different tables, but I still need the value from the first dataset. Also, I don't think [LookUp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) would work for me as I do not have Ids.

Does anyone already did something like that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create report parameters in which the available values are pulled from a query.

Then just use the parameter in your second data set.

Comment: But that does not do what I want since only 1 value of the parameter will be used.

Comment: Well, re-running the report allows you to change the values. Are you looking for something more dynamic within the report itself?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the same usage as a subreport...which means that for every contractID you'll see the second table with the appropriate informations. This might seem wierd since this is exactly what the subreport achieves..but I just can't use a subreport thanks to the sql server agent scheduler which does not accept subreport...